# Best way to prevent PHP function from being called at once when passed as a parameter?

Tags: php, closures

Consider the following code. It features `ensure_default()` helper that assigns default value to a variable IF that variable is set to false:

```
function resource_intensive_lookup() {
    echo 'Running '.__FUNCTION__.'<br>';
    return 'default_value';
}

function ensure_default(&$var, $default_value)
{
    if (! $var) {
        $var = $default_value;
    }
}

$var = 'some_value';

ensure_default($var, resource_intensive_lookup());
print_r($var);
```

The problem is that even if `$var` is set to non-false value, `resoursive_intensive_lookup()` will still be called. I could prevent that by passing just the function name as a parameter and using `call_user_func()` within the `ensure_default()`, but such approach does not scale very well if codebase has more functions that are similar to `ensure_default()`.

I have also tried to using a closure which prevents `resource_intensive_lookup()` from called needlessly, but unfortunatelly sets `$var` to `Closure Object ( )` instead of the `default_value` when initially $var starts out being set to false:

```
$closure = function () {
    return resource_intensive_lookup();
};

function resource_intensive_lookup() {
    echo 'Running '.__FUNCTION__.'<br>';
    return 'default_value';
}

function ensure_default(&$var, $default_value)
{
    if (! $var) {
        $var = $default_value;
    }
}

$var = false;

ensure_default($var, $closure);
print_r($var);
```

Comment: That's strange behavior. I've just copy-pasted your code and executed it. It works like it must work. Is it all code that you have? And which version of PHP you use?

Comment: what is the need to change current behavior? currently you are able to pass any expression as a default value. after any kind of modification you asked for it will not possible say to pass `'STRING CONSTANT'` as default value.

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev - tested this both on 5.3 and 7.1 In both cases if the script was correct, $var value should end up being 'default_value' - but that does not seem to be the case when I use the code example with the closure.

Comment: @skyboyer - you are right, I want to keep the `ensure_default` helper able to accept any expression as the default value. However if I just use the code shown at the beginning of the question, and the real `resource_intensive_lookup` takes several seconds, I would always be waiting that time - even if the $var is not false and thus there is no real need to call `ensure_default` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The last example in your question is almost good. You need to change:

```
$var = $default_value;
```

to:

```
$var = $default_value();
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want't to change `ensure_default`, the only solution I can think of is creating your own proxy that will call the callable if it will be returned by `ensure_default` and call that proxy instead of the original `ensure_default`:

```
function ensure_default_with_callback(&$var, $default_value) {
    ensure_default($var, $default_value);

    if (is_callable($var)) {
        $var = $var();
    }
}

ensure_default_with_callback($var, $closure);
// you can also call it without closure
ensure_default_with_callback($var, "not a closure");
```

Comment: I could do that, but I either need to add something that would signify whether the $default_value is a function name or just a text string. An ideal solution here would not require editing of `ensure_default()`.

Comment: You will have to change something. If you don't want to change `ensure_default` then you will have to call `ensure_default_with_callback` (as in edit) instead of `ensure_default`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass your initialisation as an anonymous function, you can then call that function only when it's needed...

```
function ensure_default(&$var, $default_value)
{
    if (! $var) {
        $var = $default_value();
    }
}

$var = 'some_value';   // Values used for testing
$var = null;

ensure_default($var, function () {
    echo 'Running '.__FUNCTION__.'<br>';
    return 'default_value';
});
print_r($var);
```

**Edit:**

If you want `ensure_default()` to be able to cope with a function or a literal value, then you can check if `$default_value` is callable...

```
function ensure_default(&$var, $default_value)
{
    if (! $var) {
        $var = (is_callable($default_value))?$default_value():$default_value;
    }
}
```

Which allows...

```
$var1 = 'some_value';   // Values used for testing
$var1 = null;

ensure_default($var1, 'default_value1');
print_r($var);
```

to set the default to a string (or in fact most other values).

Comment: I could do that, but I either need to add something that would signify whether the $default_value is a function name or just a text string. An ideal solution here would not require editing of `ensure_default()`.

Comment: I can't think of anyway of not having to alter `ensure_default()`, but I've added something which allows either a function or a value to be passed.  There is nothing in the language which allows you to call a method based on simply doing something like `$var = $default_value;`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `$var = 'some_value' || resource_intensive_lookup()`? I suppose the `'some_value'` would be a variable in the real world, but I think the snippet captures the idea.